# TypeScript's conditional always return never

Tags: typescript

I have a type that can have multiple vendors within, like so:

```
{ data: { vendor1?: {} } | { vendor2?: {} } }
```

I thought that creating a conditional type to make sure that it's there will be suiting, unfortunately I am always getting `never`. My current type looks like this:

```js
type Mapping<T> = T extends { vendor1: unknown } ? T["vendor1"] : never;
```

And usage:

```js
function someFn(input: Mapping<{ data: { vendor1?: {} } }>) {
  return input //never
}
```

Also, I tried with

```js
function someFn(input: Mapping<{ data: { vendor1?: {} } }>) {
  if ("vendor1" in input) {
    return input // still never
  }

}
```

I understand that this is because `vendor1` is always optional, but I thought this is what conditionals are for. What can I do with this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [the TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAj08W)  and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  (The list of distracting issues I see here: what's going on with the `data` property? why doesn't the second `someFn` return a value in some code paths?)

Comment: Your underlying problem is that `{foo?: Bar}` does not extend `{foo: Bar}` (you can't assign a value with an optional property to a place that has the same property as required).  But other stuff is confounding my understanding. Also note: `Mapping<{data: {vendor1?: {}}>` or `Mapping<XXX>` for any specific `XXX` type that isn't generic is going to be some specific type, and `someFn()` isn't generic. Why not write that specific type then?  When you're done fixing things, you will have something equivalent to (maybe) `function someFn({vendor1?: {}}: void), without any need for a conditional type